# Some pages not working after uploading to a server

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache

I have been making a small webshop site with php and mysql. It is working fine locally with xampp, but after uploading it to a server some of the pages doesn't display everything.

My site is built up with div tags for header, menu, centent and footer. When viewing the source from the server, I see that the html simply stops after the content opening tag. No content, close tag or footer. But this is only for 2 pages while the rest is working.

The only thing I changed before uploading was the connection to the database, but some of the working pages uses this without any problem.

Here is the code for the add_to_cart page which i not working.

```
<?php
$ID = $_POST['id'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $amount) && $amount != 0) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$ID])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$ID]['quantity'] += $amount;
    } else {
        $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, "SELECT price FROM product WHERE product_ID=$ID");
        $price = mysqli_fetch_array($r)['price'];
        echo $price;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$ID] = array('quantity' => $amount, 'price' => $price);
    }
}
header("Location: products=$ID");
?>
```

Comment: What error messages do you see in your logs?

Comment: Does the page stay empty? Is display_errors set to On in the php.ini?

Comment: It sounds like you need to debug this a littel further by looking at the error messages you are getting. Another thing to note is that your redirect will not work if you have already echoed out the price to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly be running an older version of PHP. This line only works in PHP >= 5.4 as
[dev-null-dweller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258674/dev-null-dweller) mentioned:

```
$price = mysqli_fetch_array($r)['price'];
```

possibly change to:

```
$price = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
$price = $price['price'];
echo $price;
```